# Connect remotely to Dropbox service from a server

Tags: linux, authentication, dropbox, daemon, headless

I wonder how to authenticate a remote linux server with dropbox daemon installed without X server.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: you're right. I put it threre : https://superuser.com/questions/1312148/connect-remotely-to-dropbox-service-from-a-server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I put it there because it is very hard to find the solution elsewhere from my google search in france.

My problem was : Connect a computer with dropbox installed to my account on a server where there is no graphical interface. This suppose you installed dropbox daemon from one of the many possible ways.

The fact is that I have a dropbox daemon running `dropox status` says 'Dropbox is running...' but I want my server to connect to my account.

The solution is to:

1) stop the dropbox daemon `dropbox stop`
 2) start the daemon manually on the server `cd ~/.dropbox-dist/ && ./dropboxd` this will start the dropbox daemon and display in the stdout an url on dropbox.com where as an authenticated user you can authorize the server to be connected.

That is all. This thread acts as a memo at least for me because I don't find easyly the solution each time I have to re-do this setup.

Then you have nothing else to do that run dropbox start again.

Hope this help.